# codeforces runtime error on pset 1A

Tags: c, runtime-error

I am trying to solve [problem 1A on codeforces](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1/A)

but i keep getting  Test: #1, time: 0 ms., memory: 1828 KB, exit code: 1, checker exit code: 0, verdict: RUNTIME_ERROR 
you can check my entry [here](http://codeforces.com/contest/1/submission/24683719) and find my code below , i tried to to run the program locally and it works fine and it passed the test case on the website

```
#include<stdio.h>
int calculateSquare(int n , int m , int a){
int length=0;
int width = 0;
if(n%a != 0){
    length = (n/a)+1 ;
}
else{
    length = n/a ;
}
 if(m%a != 0){
    width = (m/a)+1 ;
}
else{
    width = m/a ;
}

return length*width ;


 }
 void main(){
int n,m,a ;

scanf("%d %d %d",&n,&m,&a);
int output = calculateSquare(n,m,a);
printf("%d",output);
}
```

Comment: the posted code has LOTS of problems.  1) the valid signatures for `main()` ALL have return type of `int`,  regardless of what visual studio (and other obsolete compilers) will let you get away with.

Comment: given that the length and the width can be 1*10^9 each, if the size of each square is 1x1 then would need 2,000,000,000 squares.  Will a `int` be large enough?   The final statement: `printf("%d",output);` will not output the value to the terminal until the program is actually exited. (and almost all the online coding wants a final newline in the output. Suggest: `printf("%d\n",output);`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement. 2) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'. unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest 4 spaces for each indent level as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts.  3) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line. 4) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent).

Comment: variable names should indicate `usage` or `content` or better, both.  names like those used in the description of the problem are meaningless. Suggest using meaningful names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `int calculateSquare(int n , int m , int a)`

return type is `int` and return value is `length*width`

In the worst case `a` would be `1` and `n`, `m` would be **10<sup>9</sup>** as stated in the problem

> **Input**
>
> The input contains three positive integer numbers in the first
>   line: n,  m and a (1 ≤  n, m, a ≤ 10<sup>9</sup>).

So the return type `int` cannot hold the returned value for such case.

Better using `long long int` if the compilation is conform with C99 standard.

Comment: i think my problem is with using scanf and printf

Comment: No your code is fine the problem is from the site. Strange.

Comment: i just changed the extension of the file from .c to .cpp and it works this is weird

Comment: All the variables need to be of the same type I.E. `long long int`  (although, if I were doing it, I would use `size_t` because 1) everything is >=0 and 2)  is large enough to hold the needed values

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code as given below which seems to be working fine :

```
#include <stdio.h>

long long int calculateSquare(long n , long m , long a){
  long length=0;
  long width = 0;
  if(n%a != 0){
    length = (n/a)+1 ;
  }
  else{
    length = n/a ;
  }
  if(m%a != 0){
    width = (m/a)+1 ;
  }
  else{
    width = m/a ;
  }
  long long store = length*widthl
  return store;
}

int main(){
  long int n,m,a ;
  scanf("%ld %ld %ld", &n, &m, &a);
  long int output = calculateSquare(n,m,a);
  printf("%ld\n", output);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: is not cin and cout c++ code my code is just a c code

Comment: See the modified code, but note that it may give an overflow, since I used long instead of long long, if you wan't to avoide errors, use `cin` and `cout`. @FadySadek

Comment: `long int` is not guaranteed in C to be greater than a simple `int`.  However, for the current scenario unsigned values will work correctly.  Therefore, suggest using: `size_t`

Answer (score 0):

when trying to 'beat the clock', it is best to not use 'expensive' I.O functions.

Suggest the following two functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fastRead( size_t *a );
void fastWrite( size_t a );

inline void fastRead(size_t *a)
{
    int c=0;
    // note: 32 is space character
    while (c<33) c=getchar_unlocked();

    // initialize result value
    *a=0;

    // punctuation parens, etc are show stoppers
    while (c>47 && c<58)
    {
        *a = (*a)*10 + (size_t)(c-48);
        c=getchar_unlocked();
    }
    //printf( "%s, value: %lu\n", __func__, *a );
} // end function: fastRead


inline void fastWrite(size_t a)
{
    char snum[20];
    //printf( "%s, %lu\n", __func__, a );

    int i=0;
    do
    {
        // 48 is numeric character 0
        snum[i++] = (char)((a%10)+(size_t)48);
        a=a/10;
    }while(a>0);

    i=i-1; // correction for overincrement from prior 'while' loop

    while(i>=0)
    {
        putchar_unlocked(snum[i--]);
    }
    putchar_unlocked('\n');
} // end function: fastWrite
```

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when an uninitialized variable is passed as an `Array` or `Vector` size.

Code with error:

```
int m;
vector<int> arr(m);
//throws Exit code 2147483647
//default value of uninitialized int variable is 4201296 > 10^5
//so the vector<int> can't be created.
```

Correct answer:

```
int m;
cin>>m; //this works
vector<int> arr(m);
```